# Visual Studio 2012 does not load files in a project included using wildcards

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, csproj

I included some files in my `.csproj` file using a wildcard (editing the `.csproj` file manually), like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\**\Foo???Class.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

It worked flawlessly. But when I created a copy of my whole code tree in another directory, suddently it stopped working. When I open my original directory, it works, but when I open the copy in another directory, VS says:

> The file '....**\Foo???Class.cs' could not be added to the project.
>   The specified path contains invalid characters, is an absolute path,
>   or is a path outside of the project directory.

Why it happens? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That *worked* in your other project? The file with the question marks? Have you tried removing the question marks from the file? I don't even know how you have a file by that name, Windows doesn't allow you to name a file with question marks in it.

Comment: @tnw That is valid syntax, yes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164283.aspx, `/**/` means "any directory, recursively", `/*/` means "any directory", and `*` and `?` have their normal meaning (filename wildcard wise) as well. Also, `/` and `\\` can apparently be used interchangeably.

Comment: @Doug What part of the project tree did you copy? And where did you copy it? For all we know, `..\..\` tries to navigate down to the root of your drive and one level below it.

Comment: Oh interesting -- I was aware of the wildcard `*`, but not `?` in this context. I apologize for the stupid questions then. Thanks for taking me to school on that one :D

Comment: Beware that those are documented for *msbuild*.  Not necessarily a match for what the IDE thinks is reasonable.  I don't see an obvious failure mode when trying this, best to post this to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: The subtree I copied is at least 3 levels deep, so '..\..' should not be a problem, as it resolves inside the same tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Visual Studio has a limitation regarding the length of folder names.

The new directory (in which I placed the copied code) name was 42 characters long. The moment I reduced its name to 20 chars the wildcard magically worked, as in the original code tree.